# Attempting to search for strings and having syntax errors

Tags: vba, excel

Building a macro that sends emails to multiple firms with information from the spreadsheet itself. I'm keeping track of what firms have already been emailed by pasting the name into a separate sheet and then checking the column for the firm name and employee name.  I seem to be doing something silly.  I was thinking I could use an array to accomplish the same tasks, but are you able to search the full contents of an array?  Also, the number of firms is variable depending upon the day.

Code below

```
    firmName = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_num, firmcol)
    empName = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_num, traderCol)
    continue = True
    empSeparate = False
    emrow_num = 3

   firmAlreadyRun = emailMaster.Columns(26).Find(What:=firmName).Address
   empAlreadyRun = emailMaster.Columns(27).Find(What:=traderName).Address

    If firmAlreadyRun <> Empty Then
        GoTo Skip

    ElseIf empAlreadyRun <> Empty Then
        GoTo Skip
    End If
```

Comment: If the value is not found then the `.Address()` part will throw an error because an empty Range object has no Address property.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah ok that makes sense.  Do you have an idea of an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim firmAlreadyRun As Range, empAlreadyRun As Range

firmName = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_num, firmcol)
empName = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_num, traderCol)

continue = True
empSeparate = False
emrow_num = 3

Set firmAlreadyRun = emailMaster.Columns(26).Find(What:=firmName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set empAlreadyRun = emailMaster.Columns(27).Find(What:=traderName, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not firmAlreadyRun Is Nothing Or Not empAlreadyRun Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Skip
End If
```